# mixed distribution

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve a mixed distribution problem using the mixed distribution properties and not calculus.

However, I am having trouble finding the means.

$$f_X(x)=\frac14e^{-x}+\frac32e^{-2x}$$

Find the mean and variance of $X $.

Comment: Can you recognize the PDFs of the distributions that are being mixed? Write it as a linear combination of those PDFs to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that $$f_X (x)=\frac14 \left (e^{-x}\right)+\frac34 \left (2e^{-2x}\right) $$ so with probability 1/4 $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $λ_1=1$ and with probability 3/4 $X $ is exponentially distributed with parameter $λ_2=2$. Hence $$\Bbb E [X]=\frac14 (1/λ_1)+\frac34 (1/λ_2)=\frac14 (1)+\frac34 (1/2)=\frac58$$  Similarly you can work out the variance of $X$.